# Python: convert csv file to list of tuples

Tags: python, csv, tuples

My program is supposed to take data from a csv file and turn each row into a tuple organized by column. However when I run it, it returns the tuples as every character as a tuple element, rather than a a tuple of strings. For example if a row is organized by these columns: 'Order Date', 'Order Date', 'Group', 'Description', it should be return them as a tuple with each of those headers as an element of the tuple (4 elements). How can I fix it to return the tuples properly?

Here is the code:

```
import csv

def list_to_tuple(input_file):
csvfile = open(input_file)  #open the input file
input_content = csvfile.readlines()  #get the content of the input file and store as a double array
csvfile.close() # dont need the file anymore i can close it


final_list = []

    for lines in range(len(input_content)):
        input_content[lines] = input_content[lines].split(',')

    for lines in range(len(input_content)):
        for words in range(len(input_content[lines])):
            input_content[lines][words] = input_content[lines][words].strip()
            input_content[lines][words] = input_content[lines][words].lower()


    for i in range(len(input_content)):
        Order_Date = input_content[i][0]
        Order_ID = input_content[i][1]
        Group = input_content[i][2]
        Item_Category = input_content[i][3]
        Description = input_content[i][4]
        Seller = input_content[i][-2]
        Item_Total = input_content[i][-1]
        item = ('{},{},{},{},{},{},{}'.format(Order_Date, Order_ID, Group, Item_Category, Description, Seller, Item_Total))
        final_list.append(tuple(item))
    return final_list

input_file = 'orders.csv'
final_output = list_to_tuple(input_file)
print(final_output)
```

and here is a snippet of the incorrect output:
[image]

and here is what the csv file looks like:
[image]

Comment: **Don't post images of text**. Post *text*. Especially, don't post screenshots of some spreadsheet software... **post the csv itself**.

Comment: Have you tried using either `inputcontent[lines].split(',')` and iterating over the list returned, or using the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)?

Comment: Also, *please post your code properly formatted*

Comment: Anyway, `item = ('{},{},{},{},{},{},{}'.format(Order_Date, Order_ID, Group, Item_Category, Description, Seller, Item_Total))` creates a `str`. You then do `final_list.append(tuple(item))`. What happens when you call `tuple("hello,I,am,a,string")`?

Comment: I apologize, I was told on a previous post to post an image of the csv file content. Thank you for your input. I see it returns it as separate letters. so would this be the correct change: 
item = list(Order_Date,Order_ID,Group,Item_Category,Description,Seller,Item_Total)                          
        
final_list.append(tuple(item))

Comment: The point is nobody is going to type in the test data if it is an image.  Post as text to make it easy to use your data to reproduce the issue.  Edit your question and fix it.

Comment: @Geraldo no, you want to create a *tuple*, so `item = Order_Date,Order_ID,Group,Item_Category,Description,Seller,Item_Total` and `final_list.append(item)`

Comment: But you *really* should just use the `csv` module for this.

Answer (score 1):

Reading a CSV file using the CSV module would likely make this much simpler.

For example:

```
import csv
with open('myfile', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    output = list(reader)
```

That would get you the data as a list of lists. If you needed them to be tuples you could convert from there.